# Когда начинать изучение Asp Net Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Всем привет уважаемые! Может вопрос не туда, но я уверен что здесь мне подскажут люди с большим опытом программирования. Изучаю С# примерно 8 мес. Сейчас на протяжении 2 мес работал над своим проектом в WinForms взаимодействуя EF Core с БД MS SQL Server. Сложно совмещать госслужбу и учить вечерами язык программирования. Но я не об этом. Планирую начать разбираться по немногу с ASP net Core. Есть пробелы еще в самом языке C#, многие темы еще не изучал. Дошел до Linq(практика хорошая была при написании проекта). Стоит ли начинать c ASP? Либо разбираться дальше с языком С# html?? Спасибо!

Comment: Привет Сергей, ответ может и запоздал, надеюсь, что нет
Я думаю, что ASP .NET Core лучше всего изучать после понимания основных принципов и тонкостей работы с БД и C# в целом. Для этого практиковаться лучше на pet проектах в WPF 
Что позволит тебе лучше понимать как устроен C#
Я думаю после 3-х месяцев плотного изучения WPF, можешь потихоньку перейти на ASP .NET Core, потому что у тебя уже будет понимание что такое C# в полной мере

Comment: Тебе ничего не мешает начать это прямо сейчас, но всё же рекомендация такая 
Console Application's - Windows Forms + Access - WPF + (Postgre or MSSQL) - ASP .NET Core + (Postgre 
 + MSSQL)
В плане Фронта я не думаю что тебе стоит запариваться, используй стандартные формы Microsoft, которые задаются при создание  проект ASP .NET Core